# Remove the number of a specific section in TOC (revtex)

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

How can I remove the page number of a specific section in the TOC:
[image]

the mwe I'm using is:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
%% packges not from aps
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = red, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = black, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = black %Colour of citations
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\def\bibsection{\section{\refname}} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\section{section 1}
bla bla bla
\newpage
\section{section 2}
bla bla bla
\newpage
\section{section 3}
bla bla bla
\newpage
\section{section 4}
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would look weird, actually. Since you're using `revtex` this is not easy, as far as I know, otherwise with `tocloft` package it would be very easy.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, indeed.

Comment: @jarhead Just curious: can you explain why you need to remove the number?

Comment: @samcarter, this is the way I need to edit the document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following switches to change what is displayed in the ToC:

- `\droptocpage`: Remove page references in ToC from this point onward;
- `\incltocpage`: Restore page references in ToC from this point onward.

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% Just for this example

\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline}
\newcommand{\notoccontentsline}[4]{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{}{#4}}
\newcommand{\droptocpage}{\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\contentsline\protect\notoccontentsline}}
\newcommand{\incltocpage}{\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\contentsline\protect\oldcontentsline}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\section{First section}
bla bla bla

\clearpage
\section{Second section}
bla bla bla

\clearpage
\droptocpage
\section{Third section}
bla bla bla

\clearpage
\incltocpage
\section{Fourth section}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```